# Is there any difference between 一緒に and と一緒に?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, particles

Is there any difference between 一緒に and と一緒に?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. Could you please provide some context for this question?

Answer (score 2):

と is used with 一緒に when you want to explicitly name with whom the action is being performed. You usually need a noun/pronoun with と to make it clear who or what that is.

> 一緒に行こう！ Let's go together.
>   友達**と**一緒に行った。 I went with my friend.

By the way, と一緒に is not a set phrase as you appear to think it is. It's just a standard use of the particle と.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!